# Stop onClick from firing twice using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery.post to perform an action when a user clicks an external link. I've attached an onClick event to the link:

```
<a id="lib-geo57" onClick="javascript:dConvert('lib-geo','57');"
```

The event fires, however this action should only be performed once. To avoid a second firing, I thought of removing the onClick attribute:

```
function dConvert(a,k){
    $.post("dConverter",{aid:a,key:k});
    $("#"+a+k).removeAttr('onclick');
};
```

but that doesn't work. I also tried

```
$("#"+a+k).attr('onclick','');
```

without success. The post function continues to work in both of the above examples.

Why can't I remove or change the onClick attribute? What would be a better strategy to prevent my post from executing more than once?

Answer (score 14):

using [`one()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one) would remove the event handler after the first time the `<a>` link is clicked.

```
$('#lib-geo57').one('click', function() {
    $.post("dConverter",{aid:'lib-geo',key:'57'});
});
```

or you could define the click event using jQuery, then remove using jQuery too (but this is essentially what using `one()` does anyway).

```
$('#lib-geo57').bind('click', function() {
    $.post("dConverter",{aid:'lib-geo',key:'57'});
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

If you're sticking with the `onclick` attribute inline, then you just need to assign null to the property to remove the event handler after the first click.

```
function dConvert(a,k){
    $.post("dConverter",{aid:a,key:k});
    $("#"+a+k)[0].onclick = null;
};
```

As [another poster has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547969/stop-onclick-from-firing-twice-using-jquery/1548127#1548127), this change is client-side and so will not be persisted across page refreshes. You would need to come up with some mechanism to persist the change if that is what you need. Most web frameworks have a mechanism to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the click event by calling:

```
$("a #mylink").unbind('click');
```

Comment: I quickly tried this, after struggling with the other answers. It's closest to my original idea, and I had actually tried unbind('onclick'). It seems to be working, but how do I check that the click event has been unbound? 

I'm using Firebug to inspect the javascript.

Comment: Take a look at $("a #myLink").data('events').click in the Console- also, you should check out Firequery for Firebug: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not **stateful** between post-back events and will not remember button state or the fact that the form has been posted.

You would need to save state in a client side cookie or url attribute but this is not the best solution.

I would handle this requirement from the server side (php, asp.net etc)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mark. My "dConverter" is a rather expensive process that can take a minute or more to run. Once it has run, and the page on which the link appears is refreshed, the script is removed. We just need to capture this user interaction once. 

However, I want to prevent a user from clicking more than once until the process has completed. It looks as if some users still double-click on links!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jquery .one() function. The handler is executed at most once per element.

http://api.jquery.com/one/